# WPF Interchangable User Controls inheriting interface

Tags: .net, wpf, interface, user-controls

I have a number of user controls that implement video playback for different sources (Streaming, File, Network etc...)

I have an IVideoPlayer interface that dictates the properties/methods available on these controls.

So if I have:
UC1, UC2 and UC3 that all implement IVideoPlayer.

I have my main app that needs to have an IVideoPlayer on it, but will only know at runtime which one it should be.

I need to be able to bind to whatever IVideoPlayer is used from the main apps XAML.

Comment: You may need to provide a bit more context, ie..I am trying this approach and not sure if it will scale. With what you have now it will be difficult to provide any concrete answer.

Comment: Are you using MVVM?  This would help us give you appropriate suggestions.